# How to configure minikube ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, kubernetes

I am trying to start Kubernetes minikube (v0.32.0) using kvm on Ubuntu 18.04 following the

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/

However, it hangs while running:
`minikube start --vm-driver kvm2 -v 10` or `minikube ssh -v 10` with

`Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain`.

I can connect to minikube VM with "ssh docker@192.168.39.98", so I believe `minikube ssh` does not work because it does not use the same parameters. How do I configure it to do it?

- I did manage to login to minikube through kvm front-end using docker/tcuser and copy my public ssh key but it did not help.
- My ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json for authentication is:

> ```
> "AuthOptions": {
>             "CertDir": "/home/badgers/.minikube",
>             "CaCertPath": "/home/badgers/.minikube/certs/ca.pem",
>             "CaPrivateKeyPath": "/home/badgers/.minikube/certs/ca-key.pem",
>             "CaCertRemotePath": "",
>             "ServerCertPath": "/home/badgers/.minikube/machines/server.pem",
>             "ServerKeyPath": "/home/badgers/.minikube/machines/server-key.pem",
>             "ClientKeyPath": "/home/badgers/.minikube/certs/key.pem",
>             "ServerCertRemotePath": "",
>             "ServerKeyRemotePath": "",
>             "ClientCertPath": "/home/badgers/.minikube/certs/cert.pem",
>             "ServerCertSANs": null,
>             "StorePath": "/home/badgers/.minikube"
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your VM really starting? Are you running on bare metal or nested virtualization? Generally, your ssh private key to connect to the VM will be under:

```
/home/badgers/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa
```

You can check it with:

```
$ minikube ssh-key
```

This is also identified by the `SSHKeyPath` option in your config:

```
{
    "ConfigVersion": 3,
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "192.168.x.x",
        "MachineName": "minikube",
        "SSHUser": "docker",
        "SSHPort": 22,
        "SSHKeyPath": "/home/badgers/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa",
        ...
}
```